# Help identifying tandem frame

Tags: identify-this-bike, tandems

I bought this frame in a state off eBay a fair few years ago and have recently got it working again.

I would love to know what make or year it might be. There aren't that many his / her frames I've come across and hardly any with the same tube layout as this.

I only came across one serial number on the frame (top tube) but it was too pitted to make out and has been painted over since. The BB axles have Brampton stamped on them but that's about all I have to go on. Maybe some one knows more?

[image]

Comment: The focus is so poor that it's difficult to even guess at the age.

Comment: I'll take some more pictures if I remember. Anywhere in particular that might give more insight?

Comment: To allow more people to help you determine the approximate year, take some close-up pictures of the **pedals, crankset, brakes, and brake levers**.
Because manufacturers often use these parts across many bikes, the "style" of these parts might allow someone to narrow it down to within 5 years.
(Based on the pedals and crankset, my guess would be 1975-80)

Comment: There are some detailed pictures on Ebay for this [Sun Wasp Ladyback tandem](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Vintage-Sun-Wasp-Tandem-ladyback-/182279807852/).

The frame style appears to match your bike; see if you can match any more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, derailer (if there was one) and shifter appears to be gone.  A better view of the cranks would be helpful, as would a shot of the brakes.  Details of a few of the joints and the dropouts help to judge quality.

Comment: @BenediktBauer An approximate year would certainly help, but the question here is also about identifying the frame/manufacturer etc.   Whats a part-duplicate question - a link ?

Answer (score 0):

Your bike looks like a 1908 Humber Lady Red Tandem Original Vintage Bicycle. You can look up some pictures and it is very close. I doesn't look like anything has been changed from the original and the previous owners may have customized it a small amount (note the handlebar style) . If this is what your bike ends up being, it could be worth something. Hope this helps!

Comment: Also try the  Sun Wasp Ladyback tandem as Sam in an earlier comment said.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions coder and sam.

I don't think its a Humber as pictures i find show two tubes on the chain stays (the original picture is at a slight angle, only a single tube for the stays) also the top bearing 'cover' on the head tube is different (same as the wasp).

Also, I've seen the wasp before and though it was the one. However; the rear drop outs are different and the seat post clamps are on the wrong side and the lugs are 'plainer' on mine!

So close! encouraging stuff! Thanks for everyone looking so far!